# How to run a calculation with random numbers and keep the number set that returns the lowest delta?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to wrap my head around how to run a series of calculations using random numbers and keep the number set that returns the lowest delta from the original data set.

I am trying to recreate data by using random number constraints and want to cycle through the random numbers for a set number of cycles and then have excel  repopulate the data with the random sample set that had the lowest delta from the original data set.

I am calulating the random data set using the formula AVERAGE of the original data + RANDBETWEEN(-STDEV, STDEV). The delta is the difference between the original data and the random data set.

Sum Delta is the sum of the deltas.

Its not that I am looking for each individual random data to match the original data, but the total sum to match the original data.

The first run looks like this:

[image: Example]

So when the random number is recalculated it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: (a) add the formula for your delta. (b) can give you an example of two or three runs.

Comment: So would 883 be the number you want returned since this has the lowest delta (12)?

Comment: I would like to save the total random data set that gives a sum delta closest to 0

Comment: What are your constraints? How many cycles? This is almost like a Solver problem, but it's hard to help you further without more detail.

Comment: What have you coded/tried so far to support this question?  Knowing how you're generating the data sets and how the values are printed is quite important.  At this point, your post is `Too broad` and viable for closing.  Please update your **post** to include more detail as to make this an *objective* question.

Comment: Would Solver work with multiple data cells? I am using the average of the original data +  randbetween(-stdev, stdev)

Comment: As BigBen says, this can be done using solver, the objective would be the sum_delta equal to X...

Answer (score 0):

may try something like

```
Sub test()
Dim Ws As Worksheet, Rng As Range, Arr(1 To 6) As Variant, xSet As Variant
Dim ItrNo As Long, MinSum As Long, Rw As Long
Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set Rng = Ws.Range("A1:C8")
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
MinSum = 100000


    Do While ItrNo < 100  ' change 100 according to your requirement
    Rng.Calculate
    xSet = Range("B2:B7").Value
        'next block is only for storing each sets from column J, delete if not required
        For Rw = 2 To 7
        Ws.Cells(Rw, ItrNo + 10).Value = xSet(Rw - 1, 1)
        Next

        If Ws.Range("C8").Value < MinSum Then
        MinSum = Ws.Range("C8").Value
            For Rw = 1 To 6
            Arr(Rw) = xSet(Rw , 1)
            Next
        End If
    ItrNo = ItrNo + 1
    Loop

Ws.Range("D2:D7").Value = Application.Transpose(Arr) 'place set resulting min Delta at column D , Change to requirement
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Range A1:C8 taken for the test,  modify Range, number of iteration etc to your requirement.

NB: there are number of ways the same could be achieved, but just posted what come as first thought.

Answer (score 0):

So, made some assumptions, but this is a simple example of what may help you:

[image]